# PhpStorm. Browse remote host empty directory tree

Tags: phpstorm

I have a successful connection to server via FTP, but the directory in browse remote hosts tool is empty. Via FileZilla it works fine. How to fix that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In `Advanced options...` of the FTP `Configuration...` I have checked `Passive mode`. Now it works.